# How to scale legend elements down in a scatterplot matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Lets say I have this scatterplot and would like to keep the size of the dots in the plot but in the legend I would like to have the size denoted as 1,2,... instead of 50,100,... [image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
a2 = 300*np.random.rand(N)

sc = plt.scatter(x, y, s=a2, alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(*sc.legend_elements("sizes", num=6))
plt.show()
```

Comment: divide a2 by 50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If the numbers you want to show are just arbitrary, i.e. unrelated to the actual sizes, you can supply a list of numbers as labels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
a2 = 300*np.random.rand(N)

sc = plt.scatter(x, y, s=a2, alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(sc.legend_elements("sizes", num=6)[0], [1,2,3,4,5])
plt.show()
```

If, however, there is a relation between the numbers to show and some data,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
a3 = np.random.randint(1,6, size=N)

f = lambda a: 12*a**2       # function to calculate size from data
g = lambda s: np.sqrt(s/12) # inverse function to calc. data from size

sc = plt.scatter(x, y, s=f(a3), alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(*sc.legend_elements("sizes", num=5, func=g))
plt.show()
```

Comment: If in the scatter plot the dots have not only a different size, but also a different colour, and if the relation between size and colour is linear (let's say, a dot of size 2 is double as dark as a point of size 1), can we also display the colour difference in the legend you have suggested?