# matplotlib legend element sizes do not correspond to the values given in func

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a matplotlib scatter plot, where points sizes are logarithmically connected to points values. I would like to create a legend for this plot and I try to do that with the code:

```
x = df['A']
y = df['B']
colors = df['C']
sizes = np.log10(0.1 * df['C']) / np.log10(1.03)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
dots = plt.scatter(x, y, s=sizes, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlim(-0.005, 0.145)
plt.ylim(0, 0.06)
plt.legend(*dots.legend_elements('sizes', num=4, func=lambda x: np.power(1.03, x)))
plt.show()
```

#### Expected behavior:

I expect to see four lines in my legend where sizes of legend elements are the same as the according sizes of points on my plot.

If I remove the `func` argument from the `dots.legend_elements` method I get 4  lines in my legend. But I also want them to have correct values after the elements.

[image]

#### Reality:

I see only three lines and legend elements are not the same as the sizes in my `sizes` array.

[image]

My `func` argument seems to be the inverse of the `np.log10(0.1 * x) / np.log10(1.03)` but probably I'm using it wrong.

Comment: you want to have only 4 different sizes? (Do i understand this correctly?)

Comment: @ombk, I want to have as many as I will place in the `num` argument. Currently it is 4, yes, but I would probably like to change it in the future.

Comment: if there a way to provide us with the dataframe? is it a csv file or random uniform distributions

Comment: @ombk, the dataframe was a csv file, the `C` column contains values from 20 to 15300 distributed roughly lognormally.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428303/how-to-scale-legend-elements-down-in-a-scatterplot-matplotlib

Comment: The link I shared will help you solve your issue

Comment: @ombk, excuse me, but the way I tried to solve this is exactly the same that given in the answer (part two) in your link and it is not working.

Comment: your equation is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution***

```
func=lambda x: 10**(np.log10(1.03)*x+1)
```

**Example**

```
sizes = np.log10(0.1 * 50) / np.log10(1.03)
#output 54.44868500700143
func(sizes)
#output 49.99999999999999
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! The only slight correction would be only `func=lambda x: 10 * np.power(1.03, x)`

Comment: @BorisKalinin indeed, excuse my rusty math, i just worked it on paper and cant really remember my `log10` stuff.